# The direct subview with height 0.5 point of a UIViewController's root view is not displayed in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5.1

Some more details, I am using storyboard(xcode 5.1), the view with height 0.5 point is fine with iOS 7.1.

Please pay your attention, the view is the ***direct subview*** of the UIViewController's root view. When you put the view into a subview of the root view, it will appear.

I don't know why, it is so  weird.

Comment: check out the frame origin x and y values.

Comment: The origin x and y are correct, the value of the height is 0 on iOS 6.1 when logging.